# Can't use R language with Beaker Notebook "Error: R language backend failed!"

Tags: r, anaconda, configure, beaker, beaker-notebook

I can't figure out how to configure my setting to get `R` to work in `Beaker`? I tried both with the experimental `beaker-notebook-1.5.3-0-gb1553d1-electron-mac.dmg` version because I really don't want to use the browser for my programming.  I also tried the normal `beaker-notebook-1.5.2-0-g34d512f-mac.dmg` but got the same issue when running `R`.

## Checked where my R is located

```
$ which R
/usr/bin/R
```

## Checked which version of R i'm using

```
$ R

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
```

## My preferences .json file

```
#~/.beaker/v1/config/beaker.pref.json
{
  "languages" : {
    "IPython" : {
      "path" : "/Users/Mu/anaconda/bin"
    },
    "Python3" : {
      "path" : "/Users/Mu/anaconda/envs/python3/bin"
    }
    "R" : {
      "path" : "/usr/bin"
    }
  },
  "pref-format" : "1",
  "advanced-mode" : false,
  "allow-anonymous-usage-tracking" : true
}
```

[image]

`IPython` is working fine...

[image]

Comment: `install.packages('Rserve')`? you should also install the other packages listed [here](http://beakernotebook.com/getting-started?osx&scroll)

Comment: Yea :( I installed all of those manually and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you install R?  For me R works and it's in /usr/local/bin/R -- I installed from r-project.org.  But really it should work with R anywhere in your PATH.

Possibly the way Beaker is running R it is starting with a library path different from where you installed them?

If the problem persists please file an issue on github https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/issues

Thanks.

--

addendum: sounds like some people need to install the dependencies with the cmd line and some with R studio.  would love to hear from an R expert how to make this consistent.

Comment: Hey thanks for checking it out, I don't think it's looking for a different R since I specified the path in the json file along with the python paths.  Both are working (py2 and py3) but R isn't

Comment: So essentially I had to install all of those through RStudio, not in the terminal for some reason

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue this morning. R backend failed while IPython was running fine, only difference was me being on a Windows machine.
I tried everything given here and on other answers.
i.e. Installing all dependencies via CMD and RStudio, tried different paths, tried updating R, tried different library paths in R

Solution:

1. Go to Anaconda folder
2. Install R and activate it [Link](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/jupyter-and-conda-r)
3. Check if it works. Possibly it doesn't plot, which you can check by

   hist(rnorm(100))
4. Error you receive maybe

> Error in png(tf, width, height, "in", pointsize, bg, res, type = "cairo", : unable to load winCairo.dll: was it built?
>
> Error in jpeg(tf, width, height, "in", pointsize, quality, bg, res,
> type = "cairo", : unable to load winCairo.dll: was it built?

5. Check which version of R was installed in Conda

   R.version
6. Download and install that particular R version from [Cran website](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/)
7. Copy the file winCairo.dll

> **FROM** /YourPath/R/library/grDevices/libs/x64/winCairo.dll
> **TO**
> /YourPath/Anaconda/R/library/grDevices/libs/x64/winCairo.dll

8. Then add this  'options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = 'image/png')' in your R notebook
9. Go to step 3 and check
10. Now go to beaker.pref.json and add the path

> /YourPath/Anaconda/R

And that should solve the issues. This maybe a workaround but it worked for me.

Comment: Is there a winCairo.dll file on MacOSX? I have 3.3.1